# Is there an elegant/built-in method in C# to add a string connector IFF two strings have length > 0?

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

I know I can do this via an extension (and I do so with `StringBuilder`), but as often as I need it I feel like there has to be a better way. Let's say I am combining a first and last name, either of which may be missing (null or empty, don't care), I only want a space if both are present. So

```
return firstName + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) ? " " : string.Empty) + lastName;
```

gives me `Joe Smith` but never `Joe[trailingspace]` or `[leadingspace]Smith`.

Obviously this is a silly example, but I do this constantly in the Real World. Any better ideas?

**EDIT**: Don't suggest String.Join. It doesn't work. (Well, unless you combine it with LINQ, as spender does below.)

Comment: `string.Concat(first, space, last).Trim()`

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Yes, that does it too, but I find the order and add-to-subtract logic a little unintuitive.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Something else was bothering me about this, but it took a Real World moment to see it... That only works if the connector is a space.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with something like:

```
public static string JoinNonEmpty(string separator, params string[] values)
{
    return 
        string.Join(separator, values.Where(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v)));

}
```

Comment: Oof. Say that five times fast! (IMHO violates the "elegant" tenet of the question, but will vote you up for at least resolving the string.join flaw.)

Comment: Usually I 100% agree with you. Here it feels like overkill, and more importantly, I think the stated purpose is different from displaying an array as a string, even if that is in essence what I'm doing. What happens when you want to separate s1 & s2 differently from s2 & s3?

Comment: That would be a called feature creep! :-)

Comment: haha, awesome, but I was trying to make a point about array-joining vs. string-connecting. ;)

Answer (score 1):

From this blog [String.Join method?](http://www.paulvanbrenk.com/blog/2008/12/30/ABetterStringJoin.aspx), you could create an extension method that takes in an array and separator?:

```
string[] input = {"Joe", null, "Smith"};
return input.Aggregate((x,y)=>String.IsNullOrEmpty(y)?x :String.Concat(x, " ", y));
```

Comment: Yes, though as stated, I can use an extension, but I'm searching for something simple

Comment: An extension does make things simple. If you name it appropriately then devs wont take too long to read since they will only need the top level method.

Comment: I have nothing against extensions (and already mentioned using one), but it's just not the focus here.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use string.Format():

```
var myName = string.Format( "{0}{1}{2}"
                           , firstName
                           , !string.IsNullEmptyOrwhitespace(firstName) && !string.IsNullEmptyOrWhitespace(lastName) ? " " : string.empty
                           , lastName
                           );
```

This is not clever code relying on LINQ or extension methods, it is a standard, basic and straight forward method of doing it - importantly you can see instantly what is happening and what the result should be. Using an extension method becomes more relevant if you are looking to do the same operation in many different places.

Alternatively, your data object could encapsulate this logic:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { /*insert the string.Format() illustrated above */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: More readable than my line, I agree, but still takes a developer too long to read I think. (Sorry, I know I'm being picky.) The second method is not that different from an extension.